# Is there a general single term for benzylic-like positions in non-benzene aromatic rings?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

This is a simple vocabulary question.  Is there a single chemical term in general use that generalizes the concept of "benzyl" to aromatic but not necessarily benzene rings?

For example, in the case of phenyl or benzene rings, people talk about "[benzylamine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benzylamine)", the "benzylic position", "[benzyl bromide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benzyl_bromide)", etc.

To be more general about aromatic rings, people talk about "[arenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aromatic_compound)", and this would include not just benzene rings like in toluene or naphthalene, but also aromatic rings like pyrroles, isoxazoles, thiophenes, furans, pyridines, etc.

**So what is the "benzylic position" of a general aromatic ring called?** Is there a more general term for the "benzylic" position in compounds like [3-aminomethylpyridine](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/3-_Aminomethyl_pyridine), [furfuryl alcohol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Furfuryl_alcohol), [3-hydroxymethylpyrrole](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/21983502)?  Can I still call it "benzylic"?  Or is there a different word?

[image]

(Note: I'm not really interested in an official IUPAC-designated term here, unless that term also happens to be in general use in the chemical community.)

Comment: Well, it's not benzylic... couldn't it be just called an alpha position respective the ring?

Comment: Since the rings involved are annulenes, "annulylic" maybe?

Comment: @OscarLanzi "Annulyl" would be rather an aromatic group connected directly like phenyl not benzyl. There's for eg. furyl, tolyl, etc. but they're aryl not arylmethyl groups like benzyl.

Comment: @Mithoron Maybe I just need the word "arylmethyl"?

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=arylmethyl

Comment: Based on the suggestion from @Mithoron it seems like "arylmethyl", and maybe the more specific "arylmethylene" could be contenders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that aryl methyl is occasionally used. For example, there are references to aryl methyl ketones, which is basically a benzylic ketone if a benzene group is involved [1][2].

However, this 'aryl methyl' reference can also refer to the nomenclature of ethers and sulfides (i.e. aryl methyl ether)

Sources:

[1] https://cen.acs.org/articles/92/i4/Simple-Method-Aryl-Methyl-Ketones.html

[2] https://pubs.acs.org/doi/full/10.1021/jo062483g

Comment: Do you prefer "aryl methyl" with a space, or "arylmethyl" with no space?

Comment: I would personally prefer aryl methyl for clarity, but it isn't really something I can say as a fact. It isn't a very widely used term, I only found several references to it in published works.